# Problems enabling MMU on ARM Cortex-A8. CPU is S5PV210

Tags: arm, bare-metal, mmu, cortex-a8

These days i just want to write some bare-metal codes to deal with MMU, after days of trying, I still can't make it working. Since i can't debug it with serial console , and i don't have expensive debugger like D-STREAM, What i can do is to paste codes here and seek for help.
I don't want to be a leech, but i really don't know what futher information i can provide.

My CPU is S5PV210 based on cortex-A8 architecture
What i want to do is just doing a flat memory mapping,
which just mean "Virtual Address == Physical Address"
The codes after

```
 "ldr    pc, =0x30000000\n"
```

is just flash LED program. If a comment this line in "enable_mmu"

```
"orr    r0, r0, #0x0001\n"          /* .... .... .... ...1 Enable MMU */
```

my flash led program will work well, if i uncomment it , flash led stop working.
Here is the whole program

```
#define ttl_base 0x2F000000
#define MMU_DES_FULL_ACESS (3<<10) 
#define MMU_DES_DOMAIN (0<<5) 
#define MMU_DES_EXECUTE_NEVER (0<<4) 
#define MMU_DES_CACHEABLE (1<<3) 
#define MMU_DES_BUFFERABLE (1<<2) 
#define MMU_DES_SECTION (2) 
#define MMU_DES_ATTRIBUTE (MMU_DES_SECTION|MMU_DES_BUFFERABLE|MMU_DES_CACHEABLE|MMU_DES_EXECUTE_NEVER|MMU_DES_DOMAIN|MMU_DES_FULL_ACESS)
void init_mmu()
{
    //Create Translation Table for a flat map (Vitual Address == Physical Address)
    u32 virtualaddr,phyaddr;
    u32 *mmu_tlb_base=(u32 *)ttl_base;

    virtualaddr = 0x0;
    phyaddr = 0x0;
    while(1)
    {
        *(mmu_tlb_base + (virtualaddr>>20)) = (phyaddr & 0xFFF00000) | (MMU_DES_ATTRIBUTE); //map 0x0x30000000-0x30100000 to 0xB0000000-0xB0100000
        virtualaddr+=0x100000;
        phyaddr+=0x100000;
        if (phyaddr==0x00000000)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void enable_mmu()
{
    __asm__(
        "mrc    p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0\n"
        "bic    r0, r0, #0x3000\n"
        "mcr    p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0\n"    /* Disable Insturection cache */

        "mov    r0, #0\n"   
        "mcr    p15, 0, r0, c7, c5, 0\n"   /*Instruction cache invalidate all*/
        "mcr    p15, 0, r0, c7, c5, 6\n"   /*branch predictor invalidate all*/
        "mcr    p15, 0, r0, c8, c7, 0\n"    /* Invalidate data and instruction TLB */

        /*Invalidate entire Data cache*/
        /*Start*/
        "MRC p15, 1, r0, c0, c0, 0\n" /* Read Cache Size ID */
        "LDR r3, =0x1ff\n"
        "AND r0, r3, r0, LSR #13\n" /* r0 = no. of sets - 1 */
        "MOV r1, #0\n" /* r1 = way counter way_loop */
        "way_loop:\n"
        "MOV r3, #0\n" /* r3 = set counter set_loop */
        "set_loop:\n"
        "MOV r2, r1, LSL #30\n" /* */
        "ORR r2, r3, LSL #5\n" /* r2 = set/way cache operation format */
        "MCR p15, 0, r2, c7, c6, 2\n" /* Invalidate line described by r2 */
        "ADD r3, r3, #1\n" /* Increment set counter */
        "CMP r0, r3\n" /* Last set reached yet? */
        "BGT set_loop\n" /* if not, iterate set_loop */
        "ADD r1, r1, #1\n" /* else, next */
        "CMP r1, #4\n" /* Last way reached yet? */
        "BNE way_loop\n" /* if not, iterate way_loop */
        /*End*/

        /*Data and Instruction barrier*/
        "dsb\n"
        "isb\n"


        "mov    r0, #0\n"  
        "mcr    p15, 0, r0, c2, c0, 2\n" /*Clear L2 Translation Table Entry*/

        "mov    r4, #0x2F000000\n"
        "mcr    p15, 0, r4, c2, c0, 0\n" /*Write L1 Translation Table Entry*/

        "mvn    r0, #0\n"                   
        "mcr    p15, 0, r0, c3, c0, 0\n"    /*Write 0xFFFFFFFF to Domain Access Register, which means no permission check*/

        "mrc    p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0\n"    /* Read SCTLR */  
                                            /* .RVI ..RS B... .CAM */ 
        "bic    r0, r0, #0x3000\n"          /* ..11 .... .... .... Clear bit V、bit I */
        "bic    r0, r0, #0x0087\n"          /* .... .... 1... .111 Clear bit B/C/A/M */


        "orr    r0, r0, #0x0002\n"          /* .... .... .... ..1. Enable Aligment Check */
        "orr    r0, r0, #0x0004\n"          /* .... .... .... .1.. Enable Data Caches */
        "orr    r0, r0, #0x1000\n"          /* ...1 .... .... .... Enable Instruction Caches */
        "orr    r0, r0, #0x0800\n"          /* .... 1... .... .... Enble brach prediction */
        "orr    r0, r0, #0x0001\n"          /* .... .... .... ...1 Enable MMU */

        "mcr    p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0\n"    /* Write back to SCTLR */
        "ldr    sp, =0x3F000000\n"
        "ldr    pc, =0x30000000\n"
        "loop:\n"
        "b loop\n"
    );
}
```

Comment: How do you know the compiler didn't put `ttb` in r0-r3? A big inline asm with hardcoded registers and no clobbers is generally a very bad thing.

Comment: @Notlikethat You're right. But even if i declare "void enable_mmu(void)__attribute__((naked));". And don't use local variable. the problem stands still.

Comment: naked only affects function prologue and epilogue, which happens not to be relevant here (of course it _should_ be, but you don't tell the compiler you're trashing a callee-saved register). I just tried compiling this, and sure enough gcc puts `ttb` in r3, so that'd be well and truly trashed too. I'd recommend updating the code to something that isn't trivially broken - that much asm probably belongs in a separate .S file, at any rate.

Comment: I expect you might find some info if you leave the caches off.  Try both I/D and together.  Does that effect anything?  Where is your *vbar* and are you handling data aborts, etc.  You can get info from the FAR/FSR, etc on what is going wrong.

Comment: @Notlikethat Yeah.naked function is not important here. But i also said i didn't use local variable ttb either on the comment above

Comment: @artlessnoise I can't capture exception, because cortex-A8 exception vectore address is 0x0 or 0xffff0000, but my ddr memory address is between 0x20000000-0x60000000, so unless i successfully enable mmu, or it seems impossible to capture exceptions

Comment: @Notlikethat I've already updated my original post, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your page table init code is right. But you need to provide the `MMU_DES_ATTRIBUTE`. I think there is something wrong with the attributes.

Comment: Sorry i forget to paste it.

Comment: You can see if my attributes are right. I've updated my original post